# Problema leyendo objetos JSON en Array - Typescript

Tags: array, typescript, jsonobject

Estoy tratando de llenar mi arreglo 'enfermedades' con una petición HttpClient, pero cuando el arreglo ya esta lleno, no puedo acceder a ningún indice de dicho arreglo. Al mostrar por ejemplo this.enfermedades[0] me aparece indefinido. ¿Qué puede ser? O estoy llenando el arreglo de forma incorrecta. Adjunto la imagen del resultado que obtengo [image: Esto es lo que obtengo]

```js
findTop() {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      setTimeout( () => {
        // Arreglo enfermedades inicializado a 0
        this.enfermedades = [];
        // Ciclo for para llenar el arreglo enfermedades por medio de una petición HttpClient
        for (let a = 0; a < this.sintomasFiltrados.length; a++) {
          this.dataController.getDiagnostico(this.sintomasFiltrados[a].value).subscribe( resp => {
            this.enfermedades.push(...resp.enfer);
          });
        }
        console.log('Enfermedades', this.enfermedades);
        // Aparece indefinido
        console.log('Enfermedades poisicion 0', this.enfermedades[0]);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.dataController.getDiagnostico(this.sintomasFiltrados[a].value).subscribe
```

En esa parte del código es cuando estas llenando el arreglo, fuera de ahí aún no puedes estar seguro de que existan los elementos, por eso te marca `undefined`, recuerda que los `subscribes` son Observables y por lo tanto son asíncronos

Comment: Vas a poder ver los datos hasta que uses la promesa que está regresando tu función: findtop().then(//aquí ya está resuelta la promesa). sin embargo tu quieres actualizar datos antes de que se resuelva, o sea enseguida del código que va a tardar en regresar, eso es lo incorrecto.